# Pytorch NCCL DDP freezes but Gloo Works

Tags: python, pytorch, nvidia

I am trying to figure out whether both Nvidia 2070S GPUs on the same Ubuntu 20.04 system can access each other via NCCL and Pytorch 1.8.

My test script is based on [the Pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html#basic-use-case), but with the backend changed from `"gloo"` to `"nccl"`.

When the backend is `"gloo"`, the script finishes running in less than a minute.

```
$ time python test_ddp.py 
Running basic DDP example on rank 0.
Running basic DDP example on rank 1.

real    0m4.839s
user    0m4.980s
sys     0m1.942s
```

However, when the backend is set to `"nccl"`, the script gets stuck with the below output and never returns to the bash prompt.

```py
$ python test_ddp.py 
Running basic DDP example on rank 1.
Running basic DDP example on rank 0.
```

Same problem when disabling IB

```py
$ NCCL_IB_DISABLE=1 python test_ddp.py
Running basic DDP example on rank 1.
Running basic DDP example on rank 0.
```

I'm using the packages:

- pytorch 1.8.1
- cudatoolkit 11.1.1
- python 3.8.8

How can we fix the problem when using NCCL? Thank you!

**Python code used for testing NCCL:**

```py
import os
import sys
import tempfile
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

from torch.nn.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP


def setup(rank, world_size):
    os.environ["MASTER_ADDR"] = "localhost"
    os.environ["MASTER_PORT"] = "12355"

    # gloo: works
    # dist.init_process_group("gloo", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)

    # nccl: hangs forever
    dist.init_process_group(
        "nccl", init_method="tcp://10.1.1.20:23456", rank=rank, world_size=world_size
    )


def cleanup():
    dist.destroy_process_group()


class ToyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ToyModel, self).__init__()
        self.net1 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.net2 = nn.Linear(10, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net2(self.relu(self.net1(x)))


def demo_basic(rank, world_size):
    print(f"Running basic DDP example on rank {rank}.")
    setup(rank, world_size)

    # create model and move it to GPU with id rank
    model = ToyModel().to(rank)
    ddp_model = DDP(model, device_ids=[rank])

    loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(ddp_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = ddp_model(torch.randn(20, 10))
    labels = torch.randn(20, 5).to(rank)
    loss_fn(outputs, labels).backward()
    optimizer.step()

    cleanup()


def run_demo(demo_fn, world_size):
    mp.spawn(demo_fn, args=(world_size,), nprocs=world_size, join=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_demo(demo_basic, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using Pytorch's torchrun to make GPUs communicate using NCCL. The same page you're linking to also shows how to use [torchrun](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html#initialize-ddp-with-torch-distributed-run-torchrun). `mp.spawn()` is then not necessary, as torchrun spawns fault-tolerant child processes.